# cross-origin read blocking (corb) blocked cross-origin response with mime type text/html

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have developed a chat bot which will deployed on 3rd party website.
I wrote a script to check bot id and other parameter into that script. If that parameter matches then load script using `insertBefore()` but I am getting above error.

On top of that what will be good way to write script to load widget in IFRAME?

```js
!(function (a) {
  var b = a.getElementById ('ds-ref-id');
  if (!b) return void console.error ('Ref ID not found');
  var c = b.getAttribute ('rel');
  if (c && 'nofollow' == c.toLowerCase ())
    return void console.error ('rel="nofollow" not allowed');
  var d = b.getAttribute ('href');
  if (d && 'URL.test' != d.toLowerCase ())
    return void console.error (
      'abc reference must point to URL.test'
    );
  var e = b.getAttribute ('data-bot-id');
  if (!e) return void console.error ('abc account id not found');
  var f = b.getAttribute ('title');
  if (!f || (f && '' == f.trim ()))
    return void console.error ('abc reference must have a title');
  var g = b.innerHTML;
  if (!g || (g && '' == g.trim ()))
    return void console.error ('abc reference must have a name');
  var h = a.createElement ('script');
  (h.type = 'text/javascript'), (h.src = `http://IPADDRESS:8080?id=${e}`);
  var i = a.getElementsByTagName ('script')[0];
  i.parentNode.insertBefore (h, i);
}) (document);
```

Comment: So you're trying to load a script but the URL you are using points to something claiming to be an HTML document. Why do you think the URL should return JavaScript? What have you done to check it?

Comment: I am testing on local system. For ref you can check code above

Comment: I think i need to write iframe logic to add VUE app? @Quentin

Comment: Well, that's some more client-side code, but you didn't address my comment. The server says `http://IPADDRESS:8080?id=${e}` is an HTML document. So why are you trying to load it with a script? Did you get the wrong URL? Is there a problem with the server side code?

Comment: yes i want to load HTML on 3rd party website like freshdesk do. @Quentin

Comment: If its HTML and you know it is HTML and it is **supposed to be HTML** why are you using `<script type="text/javascript">` in the first place?!

Comment: Have you ever develop web app like freshdesk or intercom which will deploy on third party website?

Answer (score -1):

It is a common mistake, you are trying to make use of something that is not in your domain.

Your boot vue is on xx.com deployed and your "API" does not have a list of allowed domains enabled or the ability to allow all.

In short, your "API" does not allow requests from xx.com. You must enable it.

More information: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS